# Erlang tracing (collect data from processes only in my modules)

Tags: erlang, dbg

While tracing my modules using dbg, I encountered with the problem how to collect messages such as spawn, exit, register, unregister, link, unlink, getting_linked, getting_unlinked, which are allowed by erlang:trace, but only for those processes which were spawned from my modules directly? 
As an examle I don't need to know which processes io module create, when i call io:format in some module function. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: this might help ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275814/erlang-receiving-timeout-messages-when-calling-ioformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

one way is to look at *call* messages followed by *spawn* messages.

Long answer:

I'm not an expert on **dbg**. The reason is that I've been using an (imho much better, safer and even handier) alternative: **pan** , from https://gist.github.com/gebi/jungerl/tree/master/lib/pan

The API is summarized [in the html doc](https://gist.github.com/gebi/jungerl/blob/master/lib/pan/doc/pan.html).

With **pan:start** you can trace specifying a *callback module* that receives all the trace messages. Then your callback module can process them, e.g. keep track of processes in ETS or a state data that is passed into every call.
The format of the trace messages is specified under **pan:scan**.

For examples of callback modules, you may look at **src/cb_*.erl**.

Now to your question:
With **pan** you can trace on process handling and calls in your favourit module like this:

```
pan:start({ip, CallbackModule}, Node, all, [procs,call], {Module}).
```

where Module is the name of your module (in this case: sptest)
Then the callback module (in this case: cb_write) can look at the *spawn* messages that follow a *call* message within the same process, e.g.:

```
32      - {call,{<6761.194.0>,{'fun',{shell,<node>}}},{sptest,run,[[97,97,97]]},{1332,247999,200771}}
33      - {spawn,{<6761.194.0>,{'fun',{shell,<node>}}},{{<6761.197.0>,{io,fwrite,2}},{io,fwrite,[[77,101,115,115,97,103,101,58,32,126,115,126,110],[[97,97,97]]]}},{1332,247999,200805}}
```

As **pan** is also using the same tracing back end as **dbg**, the trace messages (and the information) can be collected using the Erlang trace BIF-s as well, but **pan** is much more secure.